# How can I bind two separate sub-tabs to different tables in a main tab (VBA7)?

Tags: ms-access, tabcontrol, ms-access-2016, vba7

> Basically there is a main tab control called TabCtl0 where we can
> switch from menu to other menus. For example when page1 in TabCtl0 is
> clicked it goes to the Dashboard and page2 goes to Reports and so on.
> The sidebar corresponds to the pages in TabCtl0.
>
> There are 2 "SUB" tab control and the first one is TabCtl1 and the
> other TabCtl2. They are located in page 3 for TabCtl1 and page 4
> TabCtl2 of the main tab control; TabCtl0. Now data is displayed in
> TabCtl1 from tablePersonnel and TabCtl2 is also displaying the same
> data from tablePersonnel.

I saw that the main form where the main tab control is situated is bind to tablePersonnel. When I remove this binding I got something like this - > **#Name?**
[image: profile_personnel]

> ****I just want TabCtl1 bind to table tablePersonnel and TabCtl2 bind to**
> table tableEmp**

Please I need help !

Comment: Tab pages don't "bind" to anything. You can put subforms on each tab page. This is a design, not programming issue - there is no code to analyze - and therefore not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Thank you I will change my design. I appreciate your answer. Apologies for not providing the code.